# Javascript if else with a json file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am using twitch api json files with javascript functions and I wanted to see if I could write an if else statement with a part of the json file being tested. Here is the [link](https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/OptimalBread.json) to the json file.
So now that we have the json file let me explain what I want it to do. I want to select the "stream" part of the json file and want to test it in a javascript. If "stream" == null then say Offline but if "stream" != nul then say online.
Here is the function I have so far:

```
  $.getJSON("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/"+ twitchName +".json?callback=?", function(c){
    if (stream == null) {
      document.getElementById("live").innerHTML="Offline";
    };
    else{
      document.getElementById("live").innerHTML="Online";
    }
  });
```

What am I doing wrong? Can someone please help? Thanks.

Comment: `if(c.stream ==null)`... `c` is the response object as you have defined it in callback

Comment: @charlietfl that's an answer — post it as such for acceptance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$.getJSON("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/"+ twitchName +".json?callback=?", function(c){
  if (c.stream == null) {
    $("#live").html("Offline");
  } else {
    $("#live").html("Online");
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks I am still new to javascript I really appreciate the help.